# Tridion Object Caching for Clustered Enviornment

Tags: content-delivery, broker, cache-channel-service

I'm having two Sql server 2012 DB servers in clustered environment. I have enabled Tridion Object caching. I have 2 scenarios where need help in understanding:

1. When Both servers are in Active/Active mode and Primary Server fails: Does objects cached on primary server will be available in cache memory for Failover server as well or we will lose cached objects as primary server is failed.
2. When Servers are in Active/Passive mode and Primary Server fails: I think Failover server won't be having any cached objects but please confirm on it.

Comment: Considering Ram G. answer, can you add further details to your question that whether you are looking for distributed caching across multiple servers or just for one server where your DB servers are clustered?

Answer (score 7):

You question may be more related cache channel service rather the Tridion CDA or it is little unclear as the question is mixing up on the functionality of Object Cache and CCS.

Before I answer your question, Few Important Notes on Tridion Object Caching and Cache Channel Service(CCS):

1. Tridion Object Caching on your CDA is memory based and stand alone to the local server - **Tridion Object Cache is not distributed cache. It is local in memory to the CDA. There is no feature like Object Cache Replication across other nodes on your CDA**
2. Cache Channel Service does not hold your actual Object Cache, it is mainly to notify the invalidation of cache (via RMI messages from CCS/JMS connector). The Cache channel service (Windows or JMS) will run only in Active/Passive mode and not distributed again.

Back to your questions:

**Question # 1:**
NO. The Object cache is not distributed cache, so your objects will not replicate to second CDA server and these CDA servers are independent of each other.

**Question # 2:**
This question seems to be CCS related, then YES. If it is CDA related then it is irrelevant as there is no dependency

Hope this information clarifies.

I suggest you take a look at this article to understand the object cache and CCS: http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/whatisthesdltridionobjectcache.aspx

Comment: Small remark: In point 2 you state that invalidation happens via pull by CDA. Afaik invalidation happens because the CCS *sends* invalidation signals to the subscribed Object Caches. So the CDA receives the invalidation messages. It doesn't actively poll the CCS for invalidation messages.

Answer (score 4):

Tridion object caching does not take place in the database. If your database fails over correctly, this should be "invisible" to Tridion, and any objects it is caching should remain present.

Comment: I was wondering why this answer is not popular? It is good to understand how the CCS and object cache works, but reading the question it seems to me this answer is the most relevant :) Or did I read it wrong?

Comment: Thanks Hao Peng. Maybe it's because I added it so recently.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know:

1. If your CD side configuration files is pointing to the Clustered environment and servers are in Active/Active mode, then in case of disaster, your Failover server will have cached objects
2. You are right in your assumption